How to display path-entry text box in file open dialog
When I click on Browse on different GUI applications to select a file or folder, the following screenshot is what I'm presented with:

The section I am pointing to cannot be edited just like a casual Thunar, I should manually clock on a number of folders to open the target directory rather than just copy/pasting the directory into the address bar just like this:

How can I make the window accept directory texts on the top bar?

Most file managers on Linux-style systems support pressing ctrl+l to enable the text-entry path.
By the way, the pop-up you're seeing is not a "Thunar pop-up"; it's just the file selection dialog that the GUI framework of the individual application you're using refers to.

Do you know of a way to make the input field the default behaviour?

@sjngm there's, to the best of my knowledge, no such possibility.
